# Comparing two json format strings in pandas and assigning label based on matches

Tags: python, pandas, string-comparison

I have two columns in my dataframe namely `diff` and `diff2`.

An instance of `diff`:

```
{'paths': {'modified': {'/v1/authorization/details/byDate': {'operations': {'modified': {'POST': {'requestBody': {'added': True}}}}}}}, 'endpoints': {'modified': {'{ method: POST, path: /v1/authorization/details/byDate }': {'requestBody': {'added': True}}}}}
```

```
{'info': {'version': {'from': '1.0.2', 'to': '1.0.3'}}, 'paths': {'modified': {'/equipment-status': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'parameters': {'modified': {'query': {'pei': {'schema': {'pattern': {'from': '^(imei-[0-9]{15}|imeisv-[0-9]{16}|.+)$', 'to': '^(imei-[0-9]{15}|imeisv-[0-9]{16}|mac([0-9a-fA-F]{2})((-[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5})|.+)$'}}}}}}}}}}}}, 'endpoints': {'modified': {'{ method: GET, path: /equipment-status }': {'parameters': {'modified': {'query': {'pei': {'schema': {'pattern': {'from': '^(imei-[0-9]{15}|imeisv-[0-9]{16}|.+)$', 'to': '^(imei-[0-9]{15}|imeisv-[0-9]{16}|mac([0-9a-fA-F]{2})((-[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5})|.+)$'}}}}}}}}}, 'externalDocs': {'description': {'from': '3GPP TS 29.511 V15.4.0; 5G System; Equipment Identity Register Services; Stage 3', 'to': '3GPP TS 29.511 V16.0.0; 5G System; Equipment Identity Register Services; Stage 3'}}}
```

An instance of `diff2`:

```
Backward compatibility errors (1):
error at specs/389643.json, in API POST /v1/authorization/details/byDate added required request body [added-required-request-body].
```

```
Backward compatibility errors (1):
warning at specs/419378.json, in API GET /equipment-status changed the pattern for the 'query' request parameter 'pei' from '^(imei-[0-9]{15}|imeisv-[0-9]{16}|.+)$' to '^(imei-[0-9]{15}|imeisv-[0-9]{16}|mac([0-9a-fA-F]{2})((-[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5})|.+)$' [request-parameter-pattern-changed]. This is a warning because it is difficult to automatically analyze if the new pattern is a superset of the previous pattern(e.g. changed from '[0-9]+' to '[0-9]*')
```

I want away to check if the keywords in `diff2`(always starting from API) match with any of the keywords present in `diff` and to assign them a label based on that. If all keywords match and there is no unmatching set of words, I want to assign the change as `Breaking` and if there are matching words(from `diff2`), and also unmatching(all the remaining from`diff`), I want the label to be `Both`

And if `diff2` is `Nan` then the change to be `Non-Breaking`

So for the first instance the change would be `Breaking` and second would be `Both`.

The expected output would be something like this:

```
diff                                                            diff_2                                             Change
{'paths': {'modified': {'/v1/authorization/details/byDate'      ./ API POST /v1/authorization/details/byDate      Breaking
```

This is the `to_dict()` output of my df:

```
{'diff': {11: "{'openAPI': {'from': '3.0.0', 'to': '3.0.3'}, 'info': {'title': {'from': 'Example.com', 'to': 'LN-Markets API'}, 'description': {'from': 'This is an **example** API to demonstrate features of OpenAPI specification\\n# Introduction\\nThis specification is intended to to be a good starting point for describing your API in \\n[OpenAPI/Swagger format](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).\\nIt also demonstrates features of [generator-openapi-repo](https://github.com/Rebilly/generator-openapi-repo) tool and \\n[ReDoc](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc) documentation engine. So beyond the standard OpenAPI syntax we use a few \\n[vendor extensions](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/docs/redoc-vendor-extensions.md).\\n\\n# OpenAPI Specification\\nThe goal of The OpenAPI Specification is to define a standard, language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which\\nallows both humans and computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service without access to source\\ncode, documentation, or through network traffic inspection. When properly defined via OpenAPI, a consumer can \\nunderstand and interact with the remote service with a minimal amount of implementation logic. Similar to what\\ninterfaces have done for lower-level programming, OpenAPI removes the guesswork in calling the service.\\n', 'to': 'Trade derivatives on the **[Lightning Network](https://lightning.network/).**'}, 'termsOfService': {'from': 'https://example.com/terms/', 'to': ''}, 'contact': {'deleted': True}, 'license': {'deleted': True}}, 'paths': {'added': ['/user/jwt', '/user', '/lnurl/a', '/positions', '/user/logout', '/lnurl/w', '/user/history', '/state/node', '/lnurl/w/r', '/login/credentials', '/user/deposit', '/user/withdraw', '/lnurl/a/c', '/login/joule', '/state/api', '/positions/cancel', '/user/withdraw/lnurl'], 'deleted': ['/users/{username}', '/echo']}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/logout'}, {'method': 'DELETE', 'path': '/positions'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/positions'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/positions'}, {'method': 'PUT', 'path': '/positions'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/lnurl/a'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/lnurl/w/r'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/user/history'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/withdraw'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/withdraw/lnurl'}, {'method': 'PUT', 'path': '/login/credentials'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/login/credentials'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/login/credentials'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/user'}, {'method': 'PUT', 'path': '/user'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/state/node'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/state/api'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/deposit'}, {'method': 'DELETE', 'path': '/user/jwt'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/user/jwt'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/jwt'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/login/joule'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/positions/cancel'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/lnurl/a/c'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/lnurl/w'}], 'deleted': [{'method': 'GET', 'path': '/users/{username}'}, {'method': 'PUT', 'path': '/users/{username}'}, {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/echo'}]}, 'security': {'added': ['cookieAuth', 'jwtAuth']}, 'servers': {'added': ['https://api.lnmarkets.com'], 'deleted': ['http://example.com/api/v1', 'https://example.com/api/v1']}, 'tags': {'added': ['LNURL', 'Login', 'Positions', 'State'], 'deleted': ['Echo'], 'modified': {'User': {'description': {'from': 'Operations about user', 'to': 'Interactions with the website'}}}}, 'externalDocs': {'deleted': True}, 'components': {'schemas': {'deleted': ['Email', 'User']}, 'headers': {'deleted': ['ExpiresAfter']}, 'securitySchemes': {'added': ['cookieAuth', 'jwtAuth'], 'deleted': ['main_auth', 'api_key', 'basic_auth']}}}",
  14: "{'paths': {'modified': {'/user/withdraw/lnurl': {'operations': {'added': ['GET'], 'deleted': ['POST']}}}}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'GET', 'path': '/user/withdraw/lnurl'}], 'deleted': [{'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/withdraw/lnurl'}]}}",
  15: "{'paths': {'modified': {'/user/withdraw/lnurl': {'operations': {'added': ['POST'], 'deleted': ['GET']}}}}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'POST', 'path': '/user/withdraw/lnurl'}], 'deleted': [{'method': 'GET', 'path': '/user/withdraw/lnurl'}]}}",
  17: "{'paths': {'added': ['/state'], 'deleted': ['/state/api', '/state/node']}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'GET', 'path': '/state'}], 'deleted': [{'method': 'GET', 'path': '/state/api'}, {'method': 'GET', 'path': '/state/node'}]}}",
  22: '{\'paths\': {\'added\': ["/user/history\'", \'/user/update-password\'], \'deleted\': [\'/user/history\'], \'modified\': {\'/user\': {\'operations\': {\'deleted\': [\'PUT\']}}}}, \'endpoints\': {\'added\': [{\'method\': \'GET\', \'path\': "/user/history\'"}, {\'method\': \'PUT\', \'path\': \'/user/update-password\'}], \'deleted\': [{\'method\': \'GET\', \'path\': \'/user/history\'}, {\'method\': \'PUT\', \'path\': \'/user\'}]}}'},
 'diff_2': {11: 'Backward compatibility errors (3):\nerror at original_source=specs/994.json, in API POST /echo api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\nerror at original_source=specs/994.json, in API GET /users/{username} api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\nerror at original_source=specs/994.json, in API PUT /users/{username} api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\n',
  14: 'Backward compatibility errors (1):\nerror at specs/555.json, in API POST /user/withdraw/lnurl api removed without deprecation [api-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\n',
  15: 'Backward compatibility errors (1):\nerror at specs/554.json, in API GET /user/withdraw/lnurl api removed without deprecation [api-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\n',
  17: 'Backward compatibility errors (2):\nerror at original_source=specs/552.json, in API GET /state/api api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\nerror at original_source=specs/552.json, in API GET /state/node api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\n',
  22: 'Backward compatibility errors (2):\nerror at original_source=specs/547.json, in API GET /user/history api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\nerror at specs/547.json, in API PUT /user api removed without deprecation [api-removed-without-deprecation]. \n\n'}}
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to do this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure to understand what you are trying to do, and since your example is not fully reproducible, here is mine, where:

- first row is a "Breaking" change case (all keywords match)
- second row illustrates "Both" (some keywords match)
- and third is a "Non-breaking" case (zero match):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "diff": [
            {
                "paths": {
                    "modified": {
                        "/v1/authorization/details/byDate": {
                            "operations": {
                                "modified": {"POST": {"requestBody": {"added": True}}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        ]
        * 3
        + [pd.NA, 2, "aaa"],
        "diff2": [
            "Backward compatibility errors (1): error at specs/389643.json, in API POST /v1/authorization/details/byDate added",
            "Backward compatibility errors (1): error at specs/390643.json, in API GET /v1/authorization/details/byDate added",
            "Backward compatibility errors (1): error at specs/391643.json, in API PUSH /v2/authorization/details/byDate removed",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ],
    }
)
```

First, define a [recursive](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/) helper function to get all keys from a nested dictionary:

```py
def get_keys_from_dict(d, keys=None):
    keys = keys if keys else []
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return None
    for k, v in d.items():
        keys.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_keys_from_dict(v, keys)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                get_keys_from_dict(i, keys)
    return keys
```

Define another helper function to get all keywords in a string that come after the word "API", using [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```py
def get_keywords_from_string(string):
    return (
        [item for item in string.split("API")[1].split(" ") if item] if string else []
    )
```

And another one to compare two lists of keywords with Python built-in functions [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```py
def compare(keywords, other_keywords):
    if not keywords or not other_keywords:
        return ""
    results = [item in keywords for item in other_keywords]
    if all(results):
        return "Breaking"
    if any(results):
        return "Both"
    return "Non-Breaking"
```

Finally, compose and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) those functions with the dataframe:

```py
df["Change"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: compare(
        get_keys_from_dict(x["diff"], []),
        get_keywords_from_string(x["diff2"]),
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

                                                diff  ...        Change
0  {'paths': {'modified': {'/v1/authorization/det...  ...      Breaking
1  {'paths': {'modified': {'/v1/authorization/det...  ...          Both
2  {'paths': {'modified': {'/v1/authorization/det...  ...  Non-Breaking
3                                               <NA>  ...
4                                                  2  ...
5                                                aaa  ...
```

**EDIT**

With the real dataframe you provided, in which `diff` values are strings, no dictionaries, you don't need `get_keys_from_dict` helper function, and you can simply compare columns like this:

```py
df["Change"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: compare(
        x["diff"],
        get_keywords_from_string(x["diff_2"]),
    ),
    axis=1,
)


print(df)
# Output

                   diff               diff_2 Change
11  {'openAPI': {'fr...  Backward compati...   Both
14  {'paths': {'modi...  Backward compati...   Both
15  {'paths': {'modi...  Backward compati...   Both
17  {'paths': {'adde...  Backward compati...   Both
22  {'paths': {'adde...  Backward compati...   Both
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'. I believe it must be for the Nan values, but when I replace them with `{}`, I get this error:`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'. Although, the solution is perfectly correct otherwise

Comment: I ran this on my df, and it gave me all empty strings for Change, i think the reason is that the diff also keeps changing, as in it does not always start. I have added the `to_dict()` output of my df in my question, I am not sure what is causing this potential error

Comment: The error comes from the fact that `diff` values are strings, not dictionaries objects, so `get_keys_from_dict` returns nothing. This is a different use case, I've extended my answer (at the end)  to deal with it. Cheers.

Comment: I had a small question for this, in case in `diff_2` there are multiple `API` keywords within one string, does it only count the first occurence and ignores the others?

Comment: Hi, it will collect (rather than count) all keywords, even if repeated, and not only the first occurrences. Cheers.